# unable to move files from unstage with git

Tags: git, github

I am attempting to unstage two files.  When I type git status my message is:

```
  On branch master
  Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
  Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   public/javascripts/app.js
    new file:   views/templates/caffeineTable.html
```

I used git reset HEAD and the file to unstage as shown on the command line.  However, when I follow the instructions I get back that I am on the branch master

```
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   public/javascripts/app.js
```

I followed the first step and added the file for updating.  However,
when I do a git status.  I am back at the same starting position.

I read through the docs on git https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things, but am not sure if a git checkout is what I need.

**The goal is to have everything up to date and nothing in staging.**

Answer (score 2):

You need some basic notions about git. When you are at your second step:

```
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  modified:   public/javascripts/app.js
```

git is telling you that the `app.js` file is changed, compared to the last version. Your file is (probably) up to date, but has some additional changes. You can use

```
git diff
```

to show it's difference with the HEAD version (= the last version in the history). Now git offers you two choices:

1. `git add`: you want to **stage** these changes; that means prepare these changes to commit them and keep them in the history.
2. `git checkout`: you want to **discard** these changes; this **cannot be undone**; your file will be replaced with the HEAD version of that file.